# React select not working with react leaflet popUp

Tags: reactjs, react-select, react-leaflet

I am working on react Leaflet and inside the marker popup I need to add a custom component.
And in the custom component I need to have editable dropdown.
I am using react select but the dropdown does not open when clicking it.
Here is the screen Shot.
[image]

```
<Marker position={[28.0049, 84.124]}>
            <Popup>
              <CustomPopup />
            </Popup>
```

this is the CustomPopup Component
    import React, { Component, Fragment } from 'react';

```
import Select from 'react-select';

const options = [
  { value: 'chocolate', label: 'Chocolate' },
  { value: 'strawberry', label: 'Strawberry' },
  { value: 'vanilla', label: 'Vanilla' },
];

class SingleSelect extends Component {
  state = {
    selectedOption: null,
  };

  handleChange = selectedOption => {
    this.setState({ selectedOption });
    console.log(`Option selected:`, selectedOption);
  };

  render() {
    const { selectedOption } = this.state;

    return (
      <div style={{ width: 300 }}>
        <Select options={options} isSearchable onChange={this.handleChange} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default SingleSelect;
```

Editable dropdown is not editable/clickable

Comment: You'll also need to put your code in the question (preferably as a [mcve]) so we can properly help you debug it. A screenshot isn't enough to deduce what's wrong with your code.

Comment: Please add what you have done so far and show us what is not working. A screenshot it not enough.

Comment: Updated the code. Please help me out with this.

Comment: What do you mean by editable-dropdown? What is the desired behavior you want to achieve?